# Method Validation with JSR-303/JSR-349 in a library

Tags: java, validation, aspectj, bean-validation

I am writing a library which contains a domain model and uses the Bean Validation API. My goal is to have minimal amount of dependencies. Hence, without CDI, Java EE and Spring. Allowed Dependencies are to APIs only like JSR-349 and JSR-330 API.

I can not make any assumptions about how my library is going to be used. It might be within a container or as desktop application. Forcing the library user to have an CDI, Spring, or validation implementation is not an option.

Right now, I use the bean validation API to allow the user of my library to validate the model itself. But I would also like to use Method Validation in some cases.

My questions are:

- What options do I have if I want to use method validation within a
  library project?
- Do I have to ship my library with an aspectj runtime dependency?
- Does it make sense to use Method Validation in a domain model?

Comment: If you don't want to use a heavyweight container... you could use pico container or guice. Guice has 303 hooks, but I don't think it provides a 303 implementation (though im not sure, I like hand validation)

Comment: A library should never be shipped with an container, this would make it almost impossible to integrate in an existing application.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my definition of a container here... im talking about an IOC container, a simple library. not the actual running jvm implementation. Using guice/spring/pico container still ensures you are not tied to any specific jvm implementation @Vadimo

Comment: this makes my library dependent to guice/spring/pico. This a quite big requirement for a library. Can you give some libraries that are shipped with an spring dependency?

Answer (score 0):

How is your library going to be used? Chances are that applications using it are running within CDI, Spring or another kind of container anyways, then delegating method validation to the same would be sensible.

If you really want to go for your own solution, it really depends on how the instances of your domain model are created. If you have interfaces and the user obtains instances via a factory, you might have a look at JDK dynamic proxies. Alternatively, you could check out Javassist or Cglib if you don't work with interfaces but with classes. That'd still require that your domain model nodes are obtained via a factory in order to return properly proxied instances.

Whether it makes sense or not surely depends on your specific model and its use cases. When it comes to validation of a model, property (and class-level) validation surely is the more common case, but if you provide business methods on your model and want to validate their parameters or return values, it may make sense.

Answer (score 0):

1) without CDI I would recommend apache BVal or any jsr303 specific implementation that does not require being container managed.

Since the jsr targets the java-ee platform it seems some container must manage it. what container you choose depends on the extra dependencies that must be shipped with the application.

Bval itself does not require anything other some core apache helper libraries.

2) Bval and other implementations of the jsr303 spec will need some kind of java ee container. It is a backing principle behind java ee. If no java-ee enviroment is present, bval will require a di framework to hook into.

If guice is chosen as the container; it uses cglib for its bytecode and it uses aop alliance interfaces for its aop (implemented internally with the help of cglib).

Spring does require aspectj.

If CDI is chosen, it would depend on the CDI implementation used.

3) If you are attempting to simply do method level validation, it does make sense to simply do the validation by hand in the class setter/getter itself. Specially if you want to remain platform independant.

Method level validation through the use of third party libraries only makes sense when you are using third party containers. If you are trying to have a base simple java se application, it does make a great deal of sense to put the validation in the data objects themselves and have your exception handling strategy take care of issues to the user.

The answer to three will always be rather subjective, but if you really are not looking to use a mass amount of frameworks, I don't think its bad practice to do the validation in the methods themselves.